# Object moved to here when using redirect template

Tags: dxa, dxa2.2, sites-9.6, iis-and-asp.net

We are facing very weird kind of issue, when loading a page which uses redirect page template, when it loads instead of going to target page it is showing Object Moved to here
[image]

I tried to check on site.log, couldn't find any error related to this.

please suggest

Comment: This looks like an issue with your redirect code. Some google searches indicate that this is linked to an incorrect usage of response.redirect - but we can't evaluate this without knowing how you're doing the redirect. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184596/response-redirect-results-in-object-moved-to-here